# Autoresize NSTableView's columns to fit content?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

How do I make an NSTableView auto-resize it's columns so that all content in every column is visible without truncation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
CGFloat oldWidth =0.0;
for (i=0; i<[[arrCont arrangedObjects]count]; i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<[[tableView tableColumns]count]; j++)
    {
        NSCell *dataCell=[tableView preparedCellAtColumn:j row:i];
               CGFloat  newWidth=[dataCell cellSize].width;
        if (newWidth > oldWidth)
        {
            oldWidth=newWidth;
        }
        [[[tableView tableColumns] objectAtIndex:j] setWidth:newWidth];
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as intended. With a view-based table view, this resizes the columns to the width specified in IB. With a cell-based table view, this resizes some column(s) sometimes, i.e. after executing this code several times, about three of the ten columns have resized to optimal width. I will debug this later today...

Comment: Please try this now these line needed to be change               NSCell *dataCell=[tableView preparedCellAtColumn:j row:i];